# VBA check department for existence against Active Directory

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access database which contains records that have a column "Team".
This column contains the Active Directory object "office" However, this column is not always correct.

| Team | Info |
| --- | --- |
| ABC1 | This team does not exist in AD |
| IT3 | This team exists in AD |
| ... | ... |

I want to check the column "team" of every record against the active directory, to get only the records, that have a valid team.

How can I achieve this in VBA?

I got a regex function to work in VBA, to check every record against a regular expression, however I'm not able to translate that to Active Directory related code snippets.

```vba
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Function regexp(StringToCheck As Variant, SearchPattern As String, Optional CaseSensitive As Boolean = True)

  Dim re As New regexp
  re.Pattern = SearchPattern
  re.Global = False
  re.IgnoreCase = Not CaseSensitive
  Dim m
  
  For Each m In re.Execute(StringToCheck)
    regexp = m.Value
  Next
  
End Function
```

I'm even stuck at looping just the input string itself through a loop like this, before I get further to the A issue:

```vba
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Function checkTeam(StringToCheck As String)
Dim team as String  
Dim m
  
  For Each m In StringToCheck
    team = m.Value
  Next
  
End Function
```

Comment: Why Don't you use SQL ? `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Team NOT IN ('')` or `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Team IN ('Valid Team')`

Comment: @TourEiffel I don't have a column or table with "Valid teams", that's why I cannot do this and thus need to check against the active directory.

Comment: what do you mean by `check against active directory` ? Do you want the team which have the same name than the active directory ?

Comment: I want to validate, if e.g. the string "IT3" (and every other record in "Team") exists as a department within the active directory domain services.

Comment: then just do :                  

                                 `DirStr = "IT3" ' WHATEVER YOU WANT                                              
"SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Team IN ('" & DirStr  & "')"`

Comment: For querying the AD with VBA, have a look at the VBScript examples at [SelfADSI](http://www.selfadsi.org/) and adapt them accordingly.

Comment: @HelO'Ween thank you, that resource look very helpful.